# Best practice for form validation

Tags: validation, vue.js

What are the best form validation practice for Vue? I've been using simple if tree in a method for validation `disabled` attribute  of the send button but even with just two fields it may already be many cases to validate and given I have different forms I have to copypaste a lot

Here is method I use for one of modal windows:

```js
isCryptoWithdrawalPossible() {
        if (this.sendWalletModal.amount || this.sendWalletModal.address) {

          if (this.sendWalletModal.amount && !this.sendWalletModal.address) {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = this.$t('wallets.wallets.needAddress');
            return false;
          } else if (!this.sendWalletModal.amount && this.sendWalletModal.address) {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = this.$t('wallets.wallets.needAmount')
            return false;
          }
          if (this.sendWalletModal.amount < this.sendWalletModal.method.minAmount) {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = this.$t('wallets.wallets.overLimitMinAmount', [this.sendWalletModal.method.minAmount]);
            return false;
          }
          else if (this.sendWalletModal.amount > this.sendWalletModal.method.maxAmount) {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = this.$t('wallets.wallets.overLimitMaxAmount', [this.sendWalletModal.method.maxAmount]);
            return false;
          }
          else if (this.sendWalletModal.amount > this.filteredWallets.find( el => el.currencyTitle == this.sendWalletModal.currency).avaliableFunds - this.calculateSendFee(this.sendWalletModal)) {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = this.$t('wallets.wallets.insufficientBalance')
            return false;
          }
          else {
            this.sendWalletModal.error = '';
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          this.sendWalletModal.error = '';
          return false;
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/) if you're looking for a third party lib to handle validations simply

Answer (score 1):

Update Jan 2020: here is a nice overview of vuelidate - which is kinda compared  to vee-validate (i would like to have had someone very familar with vee-validate show some more of its features but as an intro to vuelidate I liked the presentation).   https://www.vuemastery.com/conferences/connect-tech-2019/vue-form-validation

Vuelidate on github: (https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate). Until now vee-validate has been better supported, but perhaps vuelidate have themselves better organised having been under transition for a while.

Also you can take a look at this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-validator-vs-vee-validate-vs

We use vee-validate where I work, vee-validate's home page is here: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/ .
It has a nice example sandbox here: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/ .
I would recommend taking a look at the flags example in the codesandbox to see how vee-validate tracks changes on fields that it is validating.
It uses date-fns as it's default date library (which may be a concern for you if you are using moment, but I use both date-fns and moment dates with vee-validate (I use the "custom rules" feature for the moment dates)).
Once vee-validate is applied to your various form fields you can check to see if any of the fields have changed by calling a function as such:

```
hasChanged: function() {
  return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].changed);
  }
```

I have had issues with vee-validate, especially around dates, but it appears to be one of the better validation libraries out there for vue -and it appears to me that it is currently easier to get answers if you run into problems(this opinion will be biased because I have used vee-validate as against other libraries). One of the issues with vee-validate appears to be that if you change a field and then change it back to its original value then the field is still marked as changed -so you have to track initial values and current values yourself.  But in many form scenarios you have to manually track hasChanged yourself anyway, for example if you decide that viewing a form changes the status of the data (from not viewed to viewed for example) then you will need to manually record the change of a "myFormViewed" variable which is unrelated-to/outside-of the form fields.